# overriding library subflow properties in an IBM ACE Application using ibmint

Tags: properties-file, ibm-app-connect

Say I have an IBM ACE application with the following structure:

```
Application.V01
-- MessageFlow
----subflow1
-- MessageFlow2
----subflow1
----subflow2
-- Library
----subflow1
----subflow2
--------subflow1
```

Now, I am creating a bar file with overrides, using the command `ibmint package --compile-maps-and-schemas --input-bar-file "input.bar" --overrides-file "overrides.properties" --output-bar-file output.bar`

In order to override the values of the properties on the nodes in the subflow in the library in the application, I need to do something like the following, in my overrides file:

```
MessageFlow/Library/subflow1#MQ Input.connection=CCDT
```

This works fine if I've only got one message flow, and the subflows aren't nested; but (without promoting properties and doing it that way - I can't change the code now) how would I go about overriding something like `MessageFlow2/subflow2/subflow1`? Would it be `MessageFlow/Library/subflow2/Library/subflow1/#MQ Input.connection=CCDT`? Or something else?

cf. related query at [MQSeries](http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=440875#440875)